# what is psp script file?

Tags: html, perl

What kind of script file has ext psp ?

Moreover this script looks like it has perl content but it is wrapped in <% %>

Can someone tell me what this is? I cannot disclose the script due to privacy issue but I want to understand what this is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pretty S****y Privacy?

Comment: Typo? Maybe php was meant. Got any actuall code from within the file? That would help.

Comment: It's definitely perl code but I am wondering why wrapping these things under <% %>     Also this is used by webserver like CGI...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely a template for the [`Template::PSP`](http://search.cpan.org/~radcliff/Apache-PSP/lib/Template/PSP.pm) templating engine.

Comment: I looked at the code again and it has perl code wrapped in <% %> and other section contains normal looking html

Comment: It's actually apache::asp  but this answer gave me clue to look there.. thank you!

Comment: Either way it's something ancient and horrendous. Get rid of it as soon as you can!